# Option to make terraform variable to be ignored if missing

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, terraform-template

I have a .tftpl file which has the following code:

```
echo "running terraform on ${VAR_A} folder: ${VAR_B}"
```

in my main.tf I have the following, which call the above code to put variables:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.1"
}

resource "local_file" "plan" {
  content  = templatefile("plan-pipeline-template.tftpl", var.generatedvars)
  filename = "${path.module}/plan-generated"
}
```

my variables.tf is as follows:

```
variable "generatedvars" {
  type = map
  default = {
  }
}
```

I exported as env variable only 1 variable:

```
export TF_VAR_generatedvars='{VAR_A="somestring"}'
```

so VAR_B is missing when the main.tf run the *templatefile* function.

when i run terraform plan, i get the following error:

```
Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "VAR_B"
```

I was expecting to see the following result

```
echo "running terraform on somestring folder: ${VAR_B}"
```

is there any way to tell templatefile function to ignore varuables that looks like this ${..} if they are not present?

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible inside the template. Would it help you to build the actual command outside the template first and then pass it in as an argument?

```
locals {
  generatedvars = {
    VAR_A = "somestring"
  }
  command = "echo 'running terraform on ${lookup(local.generatedvars, "VAR_A", "")} folder: ${lookup(local.generatedvars, "VAR_B", "")}'"
}
```